# Long Path Problem using WScript.Arguments

Tags: vbscript, long-filenames

In continuation of [Call VBScript from Windows Explorer Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66773511/call-vbscript-from-windows-explorer-context-menu), I managed to get a VBScript file running from SendTo in the Windows Explorer.

I've changed my code to copy the file that invokes the script to my Temp folder. The new problem is that if the path is over 256 characters, I can't loop through WScript.Arguments to get all of it. Is there another way to get the full path (including the file name and it's extension)?

```
Option Explicit

Call OpenDocuWorksFile

Sub OpenDocuWorksFile()
    Const sTitle = "Open DocuWorks File"
    
    Dim iArgumentsCount
    Dim iArgument
    Dim sFilePath
    Dim sTempFolder
    Dim oFileScriptingObject
    Dim sFileName
    Dim oShell
    
    iArgumentsCount = WScript.Arguments.Count
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For iArgument = 0 To iArgumentsCount
        
        sFilePath = sFilePath & WScript.Arguments(iArgument)
        
    Next
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set oFileScriptingObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    With oFileScriptingObject
        
        sFileName = .GetFileName(sFilePath)
        
        sTempFolder = oFileScriptingObject.GetSpecialFolder(2) 'Temp Folder
        
        If .GetExtensionName(sFileName) = "xdw" Then
            
            .CopyFile sFilePath, sTempFolder & "\", True 'Overwrite
            
            Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            
            oShell.Open sTempFolder & "\" & sFileName
            
        Else
            
            MsgBox "Please select a DocuWorks file.（.xdw)", vbCritical, sTitle
            
        End If
        
    End With
    
    Set oFileScriptingObject = Nothing
    
    Set oShell = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: To get the filepath, `sFilePath =  WScript.Arguments(0) ` should be enough? Why loop through the arguments?

Comment: Hi Flakes. Unfortunately WScript.Arguments(0) only captures the beginning of the path. In testing now, 55 characters. Then WScript.Arguments(1) has 17 characters, and WScript.Arguments(2) has 17 characters also. For what it's worth, I'm using a Japanese version of Windows and the there are some characters that are "[full width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms)". Not sure if that has any connection to the problem though.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4366906/1682881. You might need to use a batch file to handle the unicode filenames.

Comment: I had a look at the link, but I have no experience with batch files or how to integrate one with my code.

Comment: Me too :). You could change your question to how to handle unicode file names in 'drops' and add the batch file tag. But usually, questions asking for code rewrites to another language is not encouraged ..And no integration will be needed as the whole thing could be done in batch, if someone knows how to.

Comment: Okay, I'll start learning to see if I can come up with a solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please leave @TylerH's edit in place - it is regarded as a good edit here. Technical writing is preferred. Thanks!